# How to read a file, abort with error if it's not valid UTF-8?

Tags: go

In Go, I want to read in a file line by line, into `str`'s or `[]rune`'s.

The file should be encoded in UTF-8, but my program shouldn't trust it. If it contains invalid UTF-8, I want to properly handle the error.

There is `bytes.Runes(s []byte) []rune`, but that has no error return value. Will it panic on encountering invalid UTF-8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    tFile := "text.txt"
    t := []byte{'\xFF', '\n'}
    ioutil.WriteFile(tFile, t, 0666)
    f, err := os.Open(tFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    s, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    s = strings.TrimRight(s, "\n")
    fmt.Println(t, s, []byte(s))
    if !utf8.ValidString(s) {
        fmt.Println("!utf8.ValidString")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[255 10] � [255]
!utf8.ValidString
```

Comment: So to summarize:

1. read input into []byte or string
2. check if valid using utf8.Valid or utf8.ValidString
3. if valid, convert to []rune if needed using bytes.Runes or []rune(str)

Thanks! I'm choosing this answer because writing a loop to go through the input - as in jnml's example - is not something I would want to do every time this problem comes up.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

// ...

buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fname)
if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

size := 0
for start := 0; start < len(buf); start += size {
        var r rune
        if r, size = utf8.DecodeRune(buf[start:]); r == utf8.RuneError {
                log.Fatalf("invalid utf8 encoding at ofs %d", start)
        }
}
```

[utf8.DecodeRune](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) godocs:

> DecodeRune unpacks the first UTF-8 encoding in p and returns the rune
>   and its width in bytes. If the encoding is invalid, it returns
>   (RuneError, 1), an impossible result for correct UTF-8.

Comment: This is pretty much the same what [`unicode/utf8/ValidString`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/unicode/utf8/utf8.go?s=8560:8591#L373) does.

Comment: @nemo Do you prefer a compiler to say "syntax error" w/o giving the line number? ;-)

Comment: Of course not, the question, as I understood it, is 'what is the best way to find out if text is valid utf8' and not 'what is the best way to find the place where my text has invalid utf8'. But that's just nitpicking, I wanted to point future readers in the direction, that your code is pretty much what `ValidString` does and nobody should use that unless for a reason (like question two). :)